# Database Products Store Images

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Need help to choose the best method to store images of products.
I will save all images in the disk, i just want to know if i should have a table to store some info for them...
I think i just have two options:

- One table where i save all the info, i will have an ID column that will be the internal name for the image, and a fk that referes the product;
- No table, the image will be saved in the disk, for example with this format XXXXX1_YY1.ext, where XXXXX1 will be the ID of the product, the YY1 will be the number of the image for the product (each product can have several images);

So i just need to know pros & cons for each option? 
Or if there's another option...

Thanks

Comment: Just store the location of each img

Comment: There is hardly any difference between the two approaches. If you have a db entry, then you can associate the same image with multiple products.

Comment: It's easier to make `<img src=...>` point to a file than to a row in a table.